# python reads some data twice device file

Tags: python, linux, file-io, linux-device-driver, bit

I'm running xillinux (more or less ubuntu 12.04) on zedboard. Zedboard combines arm with fpga.

Now have written a python script wich reads data from a device driver (/dev/xillybus_read_32).

Now i know the data i recieve is complete and correct (i used a prewritten program that stored al the data in a dumpfile, i splitted this dumpfile in frames and cheched if the content was correct ( every frame contains an addition, so easy to check).

Now when i try to recieve data from the device driver with the following python script:

```
#Read data
#Framesize
CONST_FRAMESIZE = (640*480*16)/8
#Info
frame_true = 0
frame_false = 0
#Open file
pipe_in = open("/dev/xillybus_read_32","r")
count = 0
count_false = 0
for z in xrange(1000):
        frame = "frame" + str(count) + ".raw"
        pipe_out = open(frame,"wb")
        for r in xrange(CONST_FRAMESIZE/4):
                value = pipe_in.read(4)
                pipe_out.write(value)

        pipe_out.close()

        #Compare goldendata with frame
        if filecmp.cmp("goldendata",frame):
                frame_true = frame_true + 1
                if count >= 1:
                        os.remove(frame_last)
                frame_last = frame
        else:
                print "frame_true:", frame_true
                pipe_in.close()
                sys.exit()
                #frame_false = frame_false + 1
                #os.remove(frame)
        count = count + 1;

#Close opend file
pipe_in.close()
```

I recieve all the data but, sometimes i get my 32 bit words 2 times. It's like it sometimes reads the 32bit word twice. I doesn't lose data, it just reads a 32 bit sometimes 2 times. Very strange.

Thnx

Comment: Can you show the code that you really use? This one should fail on "Compare goldendata with frame" (this is a comment, right?).

Comment: Seems like you could verify the problem by with a standalone script that read `CONST_FRAMESIZE/4` 32 bit words from the device and printed it out to see if you're actually getting any words twice or not. If so, then perhaps there's a device-driver issue.

Comment: Edited the #compare goldendata with frames, the device driver works fine. If i use for example cat /dev/xillybus_read_32 > dumpfile. I don't recieve any bitwords twice. The code before i have posted just creates a goldendata file with the right data.

Comment: Using `cat /dev/xillybus_read_32 > dumpfile` isn't the same as writing a standalone _Python_ script that does nothing by read the data from the device and print it. The whole idea is to create the simplest thing that exhibits the problem and then use that for debugging.

Comment: I know the device driver is correct, it is a project from xillybus.com. What i don't get is why the python script isn't working correctly. If i use the prewritten fifo.c (from xillybus.com) it just works fine, all data i recieve is correct.